# Design Approach to Marionette Behaviors

Tags: javascript, marionette, dry, behavior, modular

We initially approached Marionette Behaviors as a tool to build modular components for our views but that's the thing -  only to create behaviors for re-usability. There are still specific behaviors I would like to build in order to separate the view from event driven behaviors however, they would be considered too specific ie. events driven behaviors on a form that interacts with a complex template with complex business logic.

But looking past my situation, is building only modular behaviors the right path? Apparently, Marionette gives the users the freedom to use behaviors as they see fit but should we build a behavior even if its used only once?

Comment: Behaviors are generally meant to be reused across views, but I guess it would make sense to break out a complex view into multiple behaviors for easier readability...

Comment: @ThePaxBisonica I completely agree. Plus, since we haven't updated our marionette, it further prevents us from easily reusing behaviors. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Marionette behaviors are a way to extract reusable behavior from a view and then reuse it where needed, just like The Pax Bisonica writes. Although there are definitely good reasons for choosing to abstract your functionality into behaviors even if they will not be reused in other views, instead of building specific non-reusable views or to simply inherit view **C** from view **B**, and view **B** from view **A** etc.

As an example, let's say we want to have a custom view (**C**), acting very specifically. That view has x things in common with two other views, so we'll create a new view (**B**), based on a `BaseView` class (**A**), that has the common behavior. Then extend that view to create the custom view we were after (**C**).

This 'class' inheritance can get quite messy especially as the app grows. Behaviors let's you abstract the functionality to attachable objects instead. With the class inheritance approach, we would have only one `initialize` method, so if our behavior needs to add listeners etc. in the `initialize` method then we'd have to change the view right from the beginning.

A behavior is a specific purpose compartmentized which is generally a good way to go, whether you will reuse it later or not, because it's easier to understand, refactor and read.

So yes - I'd recommend you to use behaviors as much as you feel makes sense, even if the behaviors will turn out quite specific and in the end will not need to be reused, if only to keep your views leaner.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I completely agree with you.